# Restricting elasticsearch to a given index using Java API

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following code for searching in ES:

```
    Header[] headers = {new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"), new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONNECTION, "keep-alive")};
    RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder =
            RestClient.builder( new HttpHost("my-es-url",
                    443, "https"));
    restClientBuilder.setDefaultHeaders(headers);

    RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(restClientBuilder);

    SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("createdAt").from(startDate).to(endDate));
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
    searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);

    SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    System.out.println(searchResponse.getHits().getHits().length);
```

This works fine. But I see that I haven't provided the index name here. I want to restrict my search to a given index only.

How to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that when creating the `SearchRequest`:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("my-index");
```